# Override Visibility property to implement shy control

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to implement some kind of shy ComboBox. It should intercept base Visibility property and doesn't allow to show self if Items list is empty. The goal is to create smart datagrid header filter element.

I tried to intercept it using coerce value callbacks, but these callbacks should be static and can't access Items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should actually override coerce value callback. It has the following signature:

```
public delegate object CoerceValueCallback(
    DependencyObject d,
    object baseValue)
```

The first parameter `d` is actually your combobox instance, so you **can** access the Items property:

```
private static object CoerceVisibility(DependencyObject d, object baseValue)
{
    var comboBox = (ComboBox)d;
    return comboBox.HasItems ? baseValue : Visibility.Collapsed;
}
```

You must also subscribe to the changes of Items collection (or HasItems property) and call `CoerceValue(VisibilityProperty)`